# Initializing a vector of c-strings

Tags: c++, vector, c-strings, initializer-list, string-literals

Is the following code legal C++? And Why? What risk it may have?

```
std::vector<const char *> v1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

I am thinking about how this works, regarding the lifetime of the string literals. To my understand:

1. The compiler makes a temporary array of c-strings.
2. It assign the temporary array to a `std::initializer_list<const char*>`
3. Call the constructor `vector( std::initializer_list<const char *> init)`
4. Copy construct `v1` from the temporary vector.

Well, my concern is that, shouldn't the lifetime of those string literals already expired after step 3? why?

Whether or not the temporary vector exists doesn't matter. My point is if the constructor is implemented like this:

```
template <typename T>
vector<T>::vector(initializer_list<T> init)
{
  // shallow copy from init to this
}
```

Shouldn't those string literals expire, when the lifetime of `init` end after the constructor return?

Comment: What do you mean by "legal"? If you mean "should this code compile?" It's easy to check that yourself. If you, however, mean "Will this code produce UB?", please explain, your rationale, why you think, that it should.

Comment: With respect to 3 and 4, there is only one `vector` here. No temporary `vector` is created. This is an initialization so it's just a direct call to a constructor. Identical to `std::vector<const char *> v1{"a", "b", "c"};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I realize this is a silly question, once I know the answer.
From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

> String literals have static storage duration, and thus exist in memory for the life of the program.

That explains everything.